# Why do I get a ClassCastException and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, casting

Why do I get a ClassCastException and how do I fix it? I got the following Exception message. Code is below:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at HighScores.sort(HighScores.java:32)
        at HighScores.main(HighScores.java:10)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class HighScores {
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList();
        initialize( names, scores );
        sort( names, scores );
        display( names, scores );
    }

    public static void initialize( ArrayList names, ArrayList scores )
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter the name for score # " + (i + 1) + ": " );
            names.add( in.next() );
            System.out.println( "Enter the score for score # " + (i + 1) + ": " );
            scores.add( in.next() );
        }
    }

    public static void sort( ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> scores )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < (4); i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = (i + 1); j < (3); j++ )
            {
/*Line 32 -->*/ if ( scores.get( i ) < scores.get( j ) )
                {
                    int tempScore = scores.get( i );
                    scores[i] = scores[j];
                    scores[j] = tempScore;
                    String tempName = names.get( i );

                    names[i] = names[j];
                    names[j] = tempName;

                    scores.add( i, maxValue );
                    scores.remove( j );
                    scores.add( j, temp );

                    String tempName = names.get( i );
                    String maxName = names.get( j );
                    names.remove( i );
                    names.add( i, maxName );
                    names.remove( j );
                    names.add( j, tempName );

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void display( ArrayList names, ArrayList scores )
    {
        System.out.println( "Top Scorers: " );
        System.out.println( names );
        System.out.println( scores );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are reading in the scores as `String`, and trying to put the scores in an ArrayList of `Integer`.

You need to either read the score as an integer, or parse the score into an integer.

See API links below

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: Why is the exception being thrown from the `sort` method rather than `initialise`?