# Android Listview in AutocompleteTextview not responding

Tags: java, android, listview, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener

I have a problem in my application. When I try to search my application and when I click the suggested list it will respond to unfortunately close . Why is this ? How do I fix this ?

I will show you my codes and the logcat.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

AutoCompleteTextView autocomplete;
Button clear;

ListView lv;
String[] animals_names;

ArrayList<Main> animalslist;
AnimalsAdapter adapter;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class[] classes = {
    Aa.class,
    Ab.class,
    Ac.class,
    Ad.class,
    Ae.class,
    Af.class,



};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b_activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    autocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    clear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    animals_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animals_names);


    animalslist = new ArrayList<Main>();
    for (int i = 0; i < animals_names.length; i++) {
        Main country = new Main(i,animals_names[i], classes[i]);
        animalslist.add(country);
    }

    adapter = new AnimalsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), animalslist);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  
      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animals_names);


    autocomplete.setAdapter(this.adapter);
      autocomplete.setThreshold(1);

      autocomplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          AnimalsAdapter adapter1;

          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Main item = (Main) adapter1.getItem(position);

                Intent d = new Intent(MainActivity.this, item.getClazz());
                startActivity(d);

                /** Fading Transition Effect */
                MainActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

            }
        });

    autocomplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              //do nothing
          }

          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
              //do nothing
          }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
              if(s.length() != 0) {
                  clear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              } else {
                  clear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
          }
      });

}
```

}

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
String name;
int id;
Class<?> clazz;

Main(int id, String name, Class<?> clazz) {
    this.name = name;
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setClazz(Class<?> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}

public Class<?> getClazz() {
    return clazz;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


}
```

**AnimalsAdapter.java**

```
public class AnimalsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context context;
ArrayList<Main> animalslist;
ArrayList<Main> mStringFilterList;
ValueFilter valueFilter;

AnimalsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Main> animalslist) {
    this.context = context;
    this.animalslist = animalslist;
    mStringFilterList = animalslist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return animalslist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return animalslist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return animalslist.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    convertView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.b_animals_item, null);

        TextView name_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        Main animal = animalslist.get(position);

        name_tv.setText(animal.getName());

    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (valueFilter == null) {
        valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
    }
    return valueFilter;
}

private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Main> filterList = new ArrayList<Main>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                    Main country = new Main(mStringFilterList.get(i).getId(),mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                    .getName(), mStringFilterList.get(i).getClazz());


                    filterList.add(country);
                }
            }
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        } else {
            results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
            results.values = mStringFilterList;
        }
        return results;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        animalslist = (ArrayList<Main>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

}
```

**Logcat**

```
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): Process: com.example.scientificnames, PID: 1035
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter cannot be cast to android.view.Menu
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at com.example.scientificnames.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:247)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:902)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1192)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-04 02:07:17.079: E/AndroidRuntime(1035):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ArrayAdapter cannot be cast to android.view.Menu` - might want to start with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a ClassCastException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646686/why-do-i-get-a-classcastexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: yes. How to fix that ? can you help me ?

Comment: can you show me how ?

Comment: which is your `(MainActivity.java:247)`  line?

Comment: @User19 I don't think you understand what this site is for.  We are a question-and-answer site.  We are not a coders-for-hire service.  You cannot expect to dump your code base here and we'll fix it for you, especially not as quickly as you are demanding.  You need to spend some time debugging this yourself.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 This line  `Main item = (Main) ((Menu) adapter).getItem(position);`

Comment: @JoeC Sorry for I am demanding. I am just a beginner of this .

Answer (score 0):

ClassCastException use

`Main item = (Main) adapter.getItem(position);`

instead of

```
Main item = (Main) ((Menu) adapter).getItem(position);
```

**Edit**

You have two adapter one is local(String Type) another is global(Main Type)

```
autocomplete.setAdapter(this.adapter);
```

not

```
autocomplete.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here also you are using local variable use global

```
Main item = (Main) adapter.getItem(position);
```

You have two adapter one is local and another is global

> 1. Global AnimalAdapter of type Main, is child of BaseAdapter
> 2. Local ArrayAdapter of type String

May I know why these two ??

Comment: I try that but it got error (Cannot cast from String to Main )

Comment: Cannot cast from String to Main

Comment: It still error in `Main item = (Main) adapter.getItem(position);`

Comment: adapter is local here use global. give different name for local and global

Comment: why two adapter one is local and another is global

Comment: I didn't understand of what you mean . Can you show me how ?

Comment: Can you show me in my codes ? I got errors in this line `final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animals_names);` and this `Main item = (Main) adapter.getItem(position);`

Comment: remove this final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animals_names); line

Comment: Its ok but After when I search It will display this message in AutocompleteTextview (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6RV2bHcuy4uTHhpbS1KWFdrZm8)

Comment: any exception or crash ?

Comment: what I mean is after I search the word it will diisplay like this (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6RV2bHcuy4udDRxWUdOTDdIN2s) not this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6RV2bHcuy4uTHhpbS1KWFdrZm8

Comment: For clearer , This is the main page of the app [Main](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6RV2bHcuy4udDRxWUdOTDdIN2s/view), when I search the word and I will go back to the main page it will display this [Error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6RV2bHcuy4uTHhpbS1KWFdrZm8/view)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 Main item = (Main) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

instead of:

```
Main item = (Main) ((Menu) adapter).getItem(position);
```

your `Arrayadapter` initilization should be:

```
final ArrayAdapter<Main> adapter_new = new ArrayAdapter<Main>  
  (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animalslist);

  autocomplete.setAdapter(adapter_new);
```

you are using `String` as parameter which is wrong

Comment: It still says unfortunately close

Comment: check the logcat?

Comment: This is the logcat (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6RV2bHcuy4uOGJfbnF1WjNhQmc)

Comment: use different adapter variable..name ..see my code..also clean build the project

Comment: When I delete `<MainActivity.Main>` and replace to `<Main> ` it will error in `animals_names);`

Comment: final ArrayAdapter<Main> adapter_new = new ArrayAdapter<Main>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animalslist);

        autocomplete.setAdapter(adapter_new);

Comment: you have to pass `animalslist` instead of `animals_names`

Comment: if the `animals_names` will be deleted and replace to `animalslist ` it will not diplay the list when I search

Comment: how should I do that ?

Comment: it will not delete in your adapter filter method your are filtering based on Arraylist of Main

Comment: But when I use this `final ArrayAdapter<Main> adapter_new = new ArrayAdapter<Main>  
  (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animalslist); ` the list will not display when I search